# PHP, Couchbase can't store value issue

Tags: php, couchbase

We are using php driver to store documents into couchbase and from time to time we get this error message coming from couchbase:

**The object requested is too big to store in the server**

I'm a bit confused I know for fact that object that I try to store is small under 500K and default limit is 20Mb. If anybody can shine some light on what other limits are out there and anything else that I should check.

Thanks

Comment: From the source of the `couchbase` - `This error is received in callbacks. It indicates that the key and value
     exceeded the constraints within the server. The current constraints are
     150 bytes for a key and 20MB for a value` Check the size of the key.

Comment: Ahh. that is interesting. Thanks can you post a link to that document please?

Comment: https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase/blob/master/include/libcouchbase/error.h